# Basic javascript conditionals how do i add an image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, conditional-statements

alright so this is where I am stuck. For my last conditional in this basic program. I want to add an image if the user receives a score of 0. How do i add an image. I already put a picture in the folder where the .js and .html files are. But whats the code to insert that image i have on file. I wrote notes in the .js so you guys can maybe understand.

```js
//user score is 0
var userscore = 0;

//this is question 1

var question1 = prompt('What is 2 + 2?');

if (question1 === "4") 
{ userscore = userscore +1;
 alert("Congrats thats right!");}

else { alert("that is incorrect try again")}

//this is question 2 

var question2 = prompt('What is 2 * 2?');

if(question2==="4")
 { userscore = userscore +1;
  alert("Congrats thats right!")}

 else {alert("that is incorrect try again")}

//this is question 3

 var question3 = prompt("what is 20 + 5?");
if(question3 === "25")
{userscore = userscore +1;
 alert("Congrats thats right!")}

 else{alert("that is incorrect try again")}

//Scoring Guide


if (userscore === 2)
 {document.write("Congrats You have passed the test with a score of 2/3")}

if(userscore === 3)
 {document.write("Congrats You have passed the test with a score of 3/3")}

if(userscore === 1)
 {document.write("You Failed with a score of 1/3, you are not very Bright")}

if(userscore === 0)
 {document.write("You have a score of 0, your a complete idiot.")}

//I want to add an image instead of the document.write command for the last line if they recieve a score o 0
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: would i be adding the img to the html file or the .js file???

Comment: @fahimsterrrrr check my solution, let me know if you have any questions. If it works, please mark it as correct so others who may have similar problems sees the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of document.write, just create a img element, set the source, then append it to a target (and I wrote target code and if you just want to append to body instead), as such:

```
    if(userscore === 0)
    {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "/score0.png";

      var src = document.getElementById("target"); //if you want a specific source
      //var src = document.body; if you just want to append to body
      src.appendChild(img);
   }
```

You'll want to add the image to the directory of your project, as such:

- Project Directory
         -- index.html

         -- main.js

         -- image.png

In which case, you'd just put `/image.png` as the path.

Comment: `document.body` is simpler

Comment: so the name of my image file is score0.png, after the if(userscore===0) would i write {var img = document.createElement("score0.png)} I just want the image displayed if the score is 0 nothing else on the screen. The image is added to the directory

Comment: If the image is in the same directory as your is file then just do `img.src = "/score0.png"` otherwise tell me what your project directory looks like I can't read your mind

Comment: Dont mess with the create element, you put the path in the `img,src` ive updated the answer for you.

Comment: @fahimsterrrrr was this any help?

Comment: ? Which answer helped? For future developers who see your question mark the answer that you used so they know.

Answer (score 0):

This not good method. But in your case, this works. Just replace the string with img tag

```
<img  src='image_name.extension' />
```

Remember to use **single quotes**.

```js
//user score is 0
var userscore = 0;

//this is question 1

var question1 = prompt('What is 2 + 2?');

if (question1 === "4") 
{ userscore = userscore +1;
 alert("Congrats thats right!");}

else { alert("that is incorrect try again")}

//this is question 2 

var question2 = prompt('What is 2 * 2?');

if(question2==="4")
 { userscore = userscore +1;
  alert("Congrats thats right!")}

 else {alert("that is incorrect try again")}

//this is question 3

 var question3 = prompt("what is 20 + 5?");
if(question3 === "25")
{userscore = userscore +1;
 alert("Congrats thats right!")}

 else{alert("that is incorrect try again")}

//Scoring Guide


if (userscore === 2)
 {document.write("Congrats You have passed the test with a score of 2/3")}

if(userscore === 3)
 {document.write("Congrats You have passed the test with a score of 3/3")}

if(userscore === 1)
 {document.write("You Failed with a score of 1/3, you are not very Bright")}

if(userscore === 0)
 {document.write("<img  src='test.JPG' />")}

//I want to add an image instead of the document.write command for the last line if they recieve a score o 0
```

Comment: Thanks your method worked, but what would be the good method of writing the code in order to get this image? I'm trying to write the code as the first answerer told me to but it isn't working out, and when the score is 0 i get no answer.

Comment: Why did you post 2 answers?

Comment: Didnt able to answer his second question(in comment section) as a comment

Answer (score 0):

First, you should avoid copy paste same code again and again. Instead you can reuse the same code as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script>
                //user score is 0
                var userscore = 0;

                // common function for question
                var questionFunc = function(question, answer){
                    var user_answer = prompt(question);

                    if (user_answer === answer) 
                    { 
                        userscore = userscore +1;
                        alert("Congrats thats right!");
                    }else { 
                        alert("that is incorrect try again");
                    }
                }

                //this is question 1
                questionFunc('What is 2 + 2?','4');

                //this is question 2
                questionFunc('What is 2 * 2?','4');

                //this is question 3
                questionFunc('what is 20 + 5?','25');



                //Scoring Guide


                if (userscore === 2)
                    {document.write("Congrats You have passed the test with a score of 2/3")}

                if(userscore === 3)
                    {document.write("Congrats You have passed the test with a score of 3/3")}

                if(userscore === 1)
                    {document.write("You Failed with a score of 1/3, you are not very Bright")}

                if(userscore === 0)
                    {document.write("<img  src='test.JPG' />")}

                //I want to add an image instead of the document.write command for the last line if they recieve a score o 0
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Try to implement Scoring Guide also in the same manner (using the function).Then adding more questions and answers would be easy. An also rather than using plain javascript for this kind of work, better to use javascript framework like JQuery. It would much cleaner and easier.